# What is the inverse of the matrix $-X^{-2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem and in the middle of it I set that some positive semi-definite matrix is under this transformation $$-X^{-2}.$$

I dont really know how to interpret this. My first guess is that it is $-X^{-T}X^{-1}$?

**EDIT**

From the comments, if I am trying to isolate $X$ in $Y=-X^{-2}$, then $X=-Y^{-1/2}$?

Comment: It is $-(X^{-1})(X^{-1})$

Comment: $X^{-2} = (X^{-1})^2 = (X^2)^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you guys, could you comment on my edit? I added a question

Comment: Yes, you are correct.